# C++: "error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed" For constructor and invalid declaration for destructor

Tags: c++, windows, class, constructor, destructor

I have this CResources class declaration,
and i get this error

> "error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed"

```
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>


const int R_NUMBER = 5;

typedef enum {
    M,

} OBJECT_ENUM;


typedef enum {
    FILE_O,

} RESOURCE_ENUM;

typedef struct _resourcesMapping {
    CBuffer apiBuffer;
    int ObjectIndex;
};
    class CResources {
        int rCount;
        int* resources;

    public:
        CResources(int);
        ~CResources();
        int getCount();
        int getObjectsCount();
        int rOrder[R_NUMBER];
        std::set<int> ObjectsSet;
    };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Add the code before the deceleration.

Comment: where and how is R_NUMBER defined?

Comment: Looks ok, maybe you missed a semicolon before this? Can you post the whole code?

Comment: @nvoigt I have added the code before the declaration.

Comment: In my case I had missed the namespace

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to `#include <set>`.

**AFTER EDIT**

On line 18: `CBuffer apiBuffer;`, the identifier `CBuffer` is unknown.
Also, the `typedef` on `typedef struct _resourcesMapping` is ignored since you didn't declare anything.

Also, identifiers that begin with underscores are reserved in the global namespace and shouldn't be used `_resourcesMapping`.

Comment: @Aniket: What about `CBuffer`?

Comment: Are you certain this is one of the compilation units he is using? It could be a snippet from the actual source file

Comment: @Aniket: `error C4430:` is usually for unknown identifiers when the proper header is not included, etc. If the OP would tell us the line of the error we can verify this.

Comment: The CBuffer identifier is defined somewhere else. Also added struct object naming.

Comment: @talon: Please post the full error message like this: `(18) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`. Note the part with **(18)** which tells you what line number.

Comment: @JesseGood 'Error 1 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int'. Also worth mentioning that if I add 'int' to the return type of constructor it compiles.

Comment: Does it help you that the line number is 43? It's not aligned to the code snipped but it points to the constructor declaration.

Comment: @talon: I see now. The code snipped is not the same as your real code. Unfortunately, I cannot see the real code, so I won't be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct _resourcesMapping {
    CBuffer apiBuffer;
    int ObjectIndex;
}; //missing typedef name
```

it should be something like:

```
typedef struct _resourcesMapping {
    CBuffer apiBuffer;
    int ObjectIndex;
}ResourcesMapping;
```

Other than that, I don't think there are any errors. Your error seems to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need just:

```
using namespace std;
```

It helped me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Generally use of "using namespace xxx;" is a bad idea. It might cause problems later on. 
An example where it will be causing problems is shown below.

```
void functionX();

namespace mynamespace { 
  void functionX();
};
```

I recommend that prefixing is used instead such as

```
mynamespace::functionX();
functionX();
```

Hth